# Elasticsearch grand child aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following data model hierarchy: League cups -> teams -> players. League cup is the parent of teams and team is parent of players. League cup model has an attribute called country. I'm trying to write an aggregation to get list of players, and for each player get the countries he has played the league cups in. I'm having trouble writing the query. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the mapping:

```
"template" : "gamingSeason*",
"mappings": {
"leagues": {
  "_routing": {
    "required": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "eventTime": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "leagueId": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "country": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    }
},
"teams": {
  "_routing": {
    "required": true
  },
  "_parent": {
    "type": "leagues"
  },
  "properties": {
    "teamId": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
  }  
},
"players" : {
  "_routing": {
    "required": true
  },
  "_parent" : {
    "type" : "teams"
  },
  "properties": {
    "playerName": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }  
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your mapping so we can try to answer your question?

Comment: @Eli I've edited my post and added the mapping